# How to select dropdown options with dynamic id and name values using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-select, webdriverwait

I want to click a dropdown from a html webpage and click a chosen dropdown option.

Unfortunately I can't find the element because everytime I load the page the id and name values change with random letters and numbers. So I have to let the driver find using different value.

Here's the html code:

```
<span class="float-left d-sm-flex align-items-sm-center"
    style="width: 100%;font-size: 13px;line-height: 20px;color: #6b747d;height: 20px;">* Date of birth:</span>
<p></p>
    
<select class="border rounded-0 form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="xrbzm" required=""
    style="font-size: 12px;height: 2%;margin-bottom: 2%;width: 25%!important;float:left;" id="xrbzm1">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>

</select>

<select class="border rounded-0 form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="tzkrv" required=""
    style="font-size: 12px;height: 2%;margin-bottom: 2%;width: 45%!important;float:left;" id="tzkrv1">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">Septmeber</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">Dicember</option>
</select>

<select class="border rounded-0 form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="eawfb" required=""
    style="font-size: 12px;height: 2%;margin-bottom: 2%;width: 30%!important;float:left;" id="eawfb1">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Year</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
</select>

</body>
```

This is the code I used to click the dropdown options:

```
day = 6
month = 'May'
Year = 1999

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='border rounded-0 form-control form-control-sm']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/option[text()='"+str(day)+"']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='day']").click()
```

Unfortunately none of those lines work.

How can I click the value options without using `ID` or `NAME` Selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `<option>`s for *`day = 6`*, *`month = 'May'`* and *`Year = 1999`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Date of birth')]//following::select[1]")))).select_by_index(6)
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Date of birth')]//following::select[2]")))).select_by_visible_text('May')
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Date of birth')]//following::select[3]")))).select_by_value('1999')
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Comment: @Fabix Possibly you provided a handcrafted HTML and there are some elements in between the first and second `<select>` elements. But I'm sure now you got the idea how to identify the `<select>` tags wrt the parent elements.

Comment: Works fine now. 
Won't it be decteted from antibot system as it does't click the dropdown first but immeditaly clicks the option value?

Comment: [**Bot Detection**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447) is generally governed by other factors.

Comment: Manual clicks on Select and Option elements are efficiently done through Selenium using `Select()` class